# How to Store and Retrieve UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsuserdefaults

I have two `UIImageView`s and they both contain `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`, `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. So I can Zoom in/out, change `UIImageView` position and also Change rotation. I want to store that `UIImageView` `NSUserDefault` and next time when the user opens the app, it remain as it was last and also user can undo the changes they had made.

My code is:

```
-(IBAction)Undo_BtnClick:(id)sender
{
    _UndoKey--;
    NSUserDefaults *savedata = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.imageView2=[savedata objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView1%i",_UndoKey]];
    self.imageView=[savedata objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]];



}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _UndoKey = 0;

    CGFloat pointY = self.view.center.y;


    self.imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"png-0838"]];
    self.imageView2.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 220);
    self.imageView2.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, pointY*2/3);
    self.imageView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView2];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music"]];
    self.imageView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 220);
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, pointY*4/3);
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    self.Undo_Btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    self.Undo_Btn.tag = 1;
    [self.Undo_Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Undo_BtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.Undo_Btn setTitle:@"Undo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.Undo_Btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.Undo_Btn];


    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationG = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationImage:)];
    rotationG.delegate = self;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecongnizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:)];
    pinchGestureRecongnizer.delegate = self;
    [self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecongnizer];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationG];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationG2 = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationImage2:)];
    rotationG2.delegate = self;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecongnizer2 = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage2:)];
    pinchGestureRecongnizer2.delegate = self;
        [self.imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecongnizer2];
        [self.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:rotationG2];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panpan:)];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture2=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panpan2:)];
    [self.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:panGesture2];
    self.frame1 = self.imageView.frame;
    self.frame2 = self.imageView2.frame;
}



- (void)panpan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x,  location.y);
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}
-(void)SaveData
{
    NSLog(@"::: %i :::",_UndoKey);
    _UndoKey++;

    NSUserDefaults *savedata = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savedata setObject:self.imageView forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]];
    [savedata setObject:self.imageView2 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView2%i",_UndoKey]];
    [savedata synchronize];
}
- (void)panpan2:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView2];
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x,  location.y);

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}


- (void)rotationImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.lastRotation = 0;
        return;
    }
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView.transform;
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (self.lastRotation - gesture.rotation);
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);
    self.imageView.transform = newTransform;
    self.lastRotation = gesture.rotation;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}
- (void)changeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchGestureRecognizer {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pinchGestureRecognizer.view];

    CGPoint location = [pinchGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    pinchGestureRecognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
    pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
    pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
    if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}
- (void)changeImage2:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchGestureRecognizer {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pinchGestureRecognizer.view];
    CGPoint location = [pinchGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    pinchGestureRecognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
    pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
    pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
    if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}
- (void)rotationImage2:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.lastRotation = 0;
        return;
    }
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView2.transform;
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (self.lastRotation - gesture.rotation);
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);
    self.imageView2.transform = newTransform;
    self.lastRotation = gesture.rotation;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self SaveData];
    }
}
```

I get this error when I change the image view:

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UIImageView: 0x8164e00; frame = (50 223.333; 220 220); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x81674d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8165d10>>' of class 'UIImageView'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
2014-09-08 16:01:45.905 RotationGestureRecognizer[2695:c07] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UIImageView: 0x81634d0; frame = (165 7; 220 220); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8167750>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8163d00>>' of class 'UIImageView'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

Comment: You can't store UIImage in `NSUserDefaults`. You will have to store NSData of UIimage in that.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar ok thanks for response.. So how i can store that imageview's Zoom in/out,position and rotation Any idea ?

Comment: Instead of storing image view, why don't you store setting that your imageViews holding o that particular moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To "rptwsthi" i Found a Solution

For Save uiimageview Setting in NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGRect(self.imageView.bounds) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rect%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGRect(self.imageView2.bounds) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rect2%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.imageView.transform) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"transform%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.imageView2.transform) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"transform2%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(self.imageView.center) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"point%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(self.imageView2.center) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"point2%i",_UndoKey]];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
```

Retrive Back From NSUserDefaults and Set

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [self.imageView setBounds:CGRectFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rect%i",_UndoKey]])];
        [self.imageView2 setBounds:CGRectFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rect2%i",_UndoKey]])];
        [self.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"transform%i",_UndoKey]])];
        [self.imageView2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"transform2%i",_UndoKey]])];
        [self.imageView setCenter:CGPointFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"point%i",_UndoKey]])];
        [self.imageView2 setCenter:CGPointFromString([userDefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"point2%i",_UndoKey]])];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into NSData and store the Image.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageview2.image);

NSUserDefaults *savedata = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savedata setObject:data forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]];
```

Retrieve as below..

```
NSData* imageData = [savedata objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: thanks for response. I know that i dont want store imageview image i want store that imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
-(void)SaveData
{
    NSLog(@"::: %i :::",_UndoKey);
    _UndoKey++;

    NSUserDefaults *savedata = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    [savedata setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 1.0)
                 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]];
    [savedata setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView2.image, 1.0)
                 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView2%i",_UndoKey]];
    [savedata synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)Undo_BtnClick:(id)sender
{
    _UndoKey--;
    NSUserDefaults *savedata = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[savedata objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView1%i",_UndoKey]]];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[savedata objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.imageView%i",_UndoKey]]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I know that i dont want store imageview image i want store that imageview

Comment: I don't know exactly but may be you can't store cuntrol in User Default and retrieve back because cuntrol points to some memory location and when you try to load it again at that time may be some other thing is on that location